# Template page for specific node

Tags: 7, theming

I have seen a ton of examples on how to do this and I must just be fundamentally confused. I want to modify one node, in my case nid 302998. I have tried:

```
node-302998.tpl.php
page-node-302998.tpl.php
node--302998.tpl.php
page--node--302998.tpl.php
```

All to no avail. I am placing them in my templates folder. In that folder I see a few working examples of tpl files, such as `node--glove.tpl.php`, glove being one of my content types, but I see no examples of specific nodes/pages. 
I have tried clearing caches as well. I am out of ideas.

Comment: it should help https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/template-theme-hook-suggestions - explanation how drupal template suggestions works

Answer (score 1):

You can override every single node with its node id, as per your nid it should work with node--302998.tpl.php then also if its not working just enable debug mode so you can get idea how many template name available.

To enalbe debug mode open setting.php `$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;`

 refresh page again and press `ctrl + U` for view source. 

 you will get all the name those are possible with your page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a copy of the standard node.tpl.php file into your theme folder as well? It's required if you want to override the node template.